# Efficient way to unindent lines of code stored in a string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a `string[]` which contains code. Each line contains some leading spaces. I need to 'unindent' the code as much as possible without changing the existing formatting.

For instance the contents of my `string[]` might be

```
                                         public class MyClass
                                         {
                                             private bool MyMethod(string s)
                                             {
                                                 return s == "";
                                             }
                                         }
```

I'd like to find a reasonably elegant and efficient method (LINQ?) to transform it to

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool MyMethod(string s)
    {
        return s == "";
    }
}
```

To be clear I'm looking for

```
IEnumerable<string> UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(string[] content)
{
    return ???;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's all spaces, and not any tabs?

Comment: You don't want `UnindentAsMuchAsPossible` to "return" `void`, do you?

Comment: You're right @Tim. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Tim Schmelter's answer:

```
static IEnumerable<string> UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(IEnumerable<string> lines, int tabWidth = 4)
{
    if (!lines.Any())
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }

    var minDistance = lines
        .Where(line => line.Length > 0)
        .Min(line => line
            .TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace)
            .Sum(c => c == '\t' ? tabWidth : 1));
    var spaces = new string(' ', tabWidth);
    return input
        .Select(line => line.Replace("\t", spaces))
        .Select(line => line.Substring(Math.Min(line.Length, minDistance)));
}
```

This handles:

- tab characters
- source code that contains empty lines

Comment: Turns out my use case has both tabs and empty lines. This answer goes the extra mile.

Answer (score 3):

Just count the number of leading spaces on the first line, and then "remove" that many characters from the start of each line:

```
IEnumerable<string> UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(string[] content)
{
    int spacesOnFirstLine = content[0].TakeWhile(c => c == ' ').Count();
    return content.Select(line => line.Substring(spacesOnFirstLine));
}
```

Comment: This assumes the first line is least indented (which may not be the case).

Comment: @MattHouser If the program is properly formatted to begin with how could it not be the case?  Do you have an example of such a program?

Comment: Where in the original question does it say the source code is properly formatted to begin with?  The question states only that the existing formatting is to be maintained.

Comment: Also, no where in the question does it say that the code is a complete program.  It could simply be the end of a function (so no opening brace, but has a closing brace)

Comment: @MattHouser If that's the case the OP would indeed need to use one of the other solutions.  Note that if the program is quite large but it is well formatted and complete then it avoids an entire iteration of the program, so if the constraints this answer assumes *are* valid it's worth doing.

Comment: Agreed.  IF you can assume the source code is complete and properly formatted to begin with, then you can use your short-cut.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
static IEnumerable<string> UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(IEnumerable<string> input)
{
    int minDistance = input.Min(l => l.TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count());
    return input.Select(l => l.Substring(minDistance));
}
```

It moves the code to the left, all lines with the same number of spaces.

For example:

```
string testString = @"       
                     public class MyClass
                     {
                         private bool MyMethod(string s)
                         {
                             return s == "";
                         }
                     }";


string[] lines = testString.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] unindentedArray = UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(lines).ToArray();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Depending on what the OP wants, you could also improve on this by changing this: `l.TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count()` to this: `l.TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Sum(c => c == '\t' ? TabWidth : 1)` where `TabWidth` is something like 4.

Comment: Another improvement would be to handle empty lines. Typically if someone writes code that has an empty line, the empty line contains nothing but the "\r\n". This code won't handle that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a little LINQ and Regex to find the shortest indentation, then remove that number of characters from all lines.

```
string[] l_lines = { 
                        "                                         public class MyClass",
                        "                                         {",
                        "                                             private bool MyMethod(string s)",
                        "                                             {",
                        "                                                 return s == \"\";",
                        "                                             }",
                        "                                         }"  
                   };

int l_smallestIndentation =
    l_lines.Min( s => Regex.Match( s, "^\\s*" ).Value.Length );

string[] l_result =
    l_lines.Select( s => s.Substring( l_smallestIndentation ) )
           .ToArray();

foreach ( string l_line in l_result )
    Console.WriteLine( l_line );
```

Prints:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private bool MyMethod(string s)
    {
        return s == "";
    }
}
```

This program will scan all strings in the array. If you can assume that the first line is the least indented, then you could improve performance by scanning only the first line:

```
int l_smallestIndentation =
    Regex.Match( l_lines[0], "^\\s*" ).Value.Length;
```

Also note that this will handle a tab character (`"\t"`) as a single character. If there is a mix of tabs and spaces, then reversing the indent may be tricky. The easiest way to handle that would be to replace all instances of tabs with the appropriate number of spaces (often 4, though individual applications can vary wildly) *before* running the code above.

It would also be possible to modify the code above to give additional weight to tabs. At that point, the regex is no longer of much use.

```
string[] l_lines = { 
        "\t\t\tpublic class MyClass",
        "                        {",
        "                                private bool MyMethod(string s)",
        "                                {",
        "        \t        \t\treturn s == \"\";",
        "                                }",
        "\t\t\t}"  
    };

int l_tabWeight = 8;
int l_smallestIndentation =
    l_lines.Min
    (
        s => s.ToCharArray()
              .TakeWhile( c => Char.IsWhiteSpace( c ) )
              .Select( c => c == '\t' ? l_tabWeight : 1 )
              .Sum()
    );

string[] l_result =
    l_lines.Select
    (
        s =>
        {
            int l_whitespaceToRemove = l_smallestIndentation;
            while ( l_whitespaceToRemove > 0 )
            {
                l_whitespaceToRemove -= s[0] == '\t' ? l_tabWeight : 1;
                s = s.Substring( 1 );
            }
            return s;
        }
    ).ToArray();
```

Prints (assuming your console window has a tab width of 8 like mine):

```
public class MyClass
{
        private bool MyMethod(string s)
        {
                return s == "";
        }
}
```

*You may need to modify this code to work with edge-case scenarios, such as zero-length lines or lines containing only whitespaces.*

Answer (score 1):

This will first find the minimum ident and then remove that number of spaces for each line.

```
var code = new [] { "  foo", "   bar" };

var minIndent = code.Select(line => line.TakeWhile(ch => ch == ' ').Count()).Min();
var formatted = code.Select(line => line.Remove(0, minIndent));
```

It would be possible to write everything in one single expression, but while it is more functionally elegant I think that the `minIndent` variable makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

To match your desired method interface:

```
IEnumerable<string> UnindentAsMuchAsPossible(string[] content)
{
  int minIndent = content.Select(s => s.TakeWhile(c => c == ' ').Count()).Min();
  return content.Select(s => s.Substring(minIndent)).AsEnumerable();
}
```

This gets the minimum indent of all lines (assumes spaces only, no tabs), then strips `minIndent` spaces from the start of each line and returns that as `IEnumerable`.